# Spring Cloud Zuul/Eureka dynamic route

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am using spring cloud eureka and spring cloud zuul proxy and i was wondering if there is any way to add dymanic zuul routes when a new service is register in eureka server or the only way to add a route is edit the application.yml file and restart the spring zuul application

```
zuul:
  ignoredPatterns: /**/admin/**
  routes:
    users: /myusers/**
```

Comment: That will be a cool thing to have but I do not think there is anything like that  right now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If your Zuul server is also EurekaClient (use @EnableDiscoveryClient annotation) it will discover all the services and automatically will create routes.

Ex. Zuul server is zuul.mydomain.com
Eureka has 2 services registered with it : orders and accounts

Then Zuul will automatically have two routes 
Zuul.mydomain.com/orders and Zuul.mydomain.com/accounts

And this will forward to particular service. It will also automatically load balance calls for you if services run on multiple machines.

Comment: Thanks, I added @EnableDiscoveryClient to my Zuul class and all services from eureka were discovered with automatic routes.

Comment: I love it :), its so simple to experiment with microservices using it, rigth now i have eureka, zuul and two microservices working with just a few lines of code, now i will add spring cloud hystrix, cloud config and cloud bus

Comment: @vladsfl, is there a way to control the routes? For e.g. how to map service orders to  Zuul.mydomain.com/notorders (could not think of a nice name)?

Comment: in case you added ` @EnableDiscoveryClient` and didn't work make sure you also add the depedency `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>` as well otherwise you won't see it listed in eureka server

Comment: You probably don't want the server dependency, `spring-cloud-starter-eureka` should work just fine.