# Springcloud: Zuul + Eureka not working

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I spent all day trying to make Zuul + Eureka work together, but I hasn't been lucky with that. Zuul alone, without Eureka, works fine. I've tried a lot of different configurations like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084130/6433166), which says that all I have to do is turn Zull in an Eureka client (by using @EnableDiscoveryClient at root application class).

My setup is very simple: it consists of a **service:8080** (service 1), **Zuul:9000** and **Eureka:8761**.

All the approaches I've tried using Eureka gave me the same error when I tried to access service 1 using Zull (`http://localhost:9000/service1` in this case):

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
(...)
com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: service1
```

Service 1 is working fine (I can access it directly from the browser address bar `http://localhost:8080`) and Eureka shows both Zull and Service 1 correctly registered:

[image]

The apps are configured like:

Service 1 (bootstrap.yml):

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service1
```

Service 1 (application.yml):

```
eureka:
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
        leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
```

Zuul:

```
ribbon:
    eureka:
        enabled: false

eureka:
    instance:
        leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 1
        leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 2
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://127.0.0.1:8761/eureka/
    healthcheck:
        enabled: true

server:
    port: 9000
```

Eureka:

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false

logging:
  level:
    com:
      netflix:
        eureka: OFF
        discovery: OFF
```

Zuul Annotations at root application class:

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

Am I missing any important point?

Comment: Can you try removing `ribbon.eureka.enabled: false`?

Comment: Yup, you've disabled ribbon's eureka support.

Comment: @RyanBaxter, spencergibb, I commented the ribbon.eureka.enabled: false part. It worked. It's annoying when you must do something you just know anything about it. I'm learning. Thank you!