# Spring Cloud Zuul: how to add route without restart

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I am writing microservices with Spring Cloud.

I'm also using Zuul as the API Gateway which routes some URLs to destination services which are **not** registered into Eureka.

When a new route needed to be added to Zuul, we often edit the application.yml file and then restart the Zuul server.

I was wondering is there a way to add new route into Zuul without restarting the Zuul server?

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37054643/spring-cloud-zuul-eureka-dynamic-route) useful but it only works for services registed in Erueka.

Comment: If you are using Spring Cloud Config (and config server) you could update the `routes` in your config repo and that configuration can be updated in your Zuul app without requiring a restart.  Your routes configuration can be refresh manually by making a `POST` to `/routes`.  http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Camden.SR6/#_the_routes_endpoint

Comment: Thanks Ryan, that helps a lot.