# Zuul multiple wildcards and nested routes

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

Using Zuul (version 1.3.1) I want to have the following routes config:

```
zuul:
    routes:
        serviceA: 
            path: /us/*/a/**
            serviceId: serviceA
            strip-prefix: false
        serviceB:
            path: /us/*/b/**
            serviceId: serviceB
            strip-prefix: false
```

I could not find a reference on how the path parameter is treated and supposed to look like. Zuul seems to work correctly in my environment, as I can successfully use path /us/** for example.

But **multiple wildcards** in the path do not seem to work. Is this supposed to work? What would be a workaround if not? Are nested routes possible?

Comment: Seems as dublicate or similar to: [Is it possible to configure Zuul routes to match on wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54651148/is-it-possible-to-configure-zuul-routes-to-match-on-wildcards). > /api/\*admin/v1.1/user\** works fine Also have a look in spec [Embedded Zuul Reverse Proxy](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR5/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html)